# bootloader issues: grub error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I tried installing Ubuntu on Lenovo 710 Yoga, 256GB SSD, but my ubuntu was not starting after installation. It was struck at the booting page which has Ubuntu on the display and few dots below that with changing color.
Because of this I booted on to windows and deleted the Ubuntu partition and now when I restart I always get the GRUB error and Ubuntu grub seems to be loading. 
I can log on to windows 10 only by going to boot loader and selecting the Windows loader. 
Can someone help me out on this as I do not have a windows 10 repair CD

Comment: Wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop, and I fixed it in this way:

When starting on the computer, in the operative system selector, instead of choosing Ubuntu, choose the advanced options and then press <kbd>e</kbd>.

That will let you edit the grub before loading Ubuntu. So after something written about "splash" type `acpi=off` and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

(That will let you start Ubuntu)

Although, those changes are not permanent. So you need to do this too:

- After Ubuntu started, open the terminal and write `sudo nautilus` (that will open the files explorer in root mode)
- Go to, Computer > `/etc/default` and open the file `grub`. There you should replace

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  ```

  for

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off".
  ```

  That will make those changes permanent.

---

BTW, I have some issues that I can't resolve:

- I can't shutdown the computer, and I've tried everything that I found on this forum.
- There is no battery icon that shows how much battery do I have left, and I have also tried everything.

Any help?